# How to show a specific amount of child divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not sure if this is possible...
If you have f.ex.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
    <div id="child3"></div>
    <div id="child4"></div>
    <div id="child5"></div>
    <div id="child6"></div>
</div>
```

How could you, with jquery or javascript (or anything for that matter), just show the first two?

Comment: What do you want to do? Looking at your code we can at most say "Yup, it does what it is written to do", which presumably isn't what you want...

Comment: It's solved already. I just wanted to hide all except the first two, then (I didn't ask for it, but I needed it and got it) show the next 5 with a button click. :lt selector did it for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`:gt()` jQuery selector](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/).

```
$("#parent>div:gt(1)").hide()
```

Actually, if you want to show incrementally, it is better to hide everything first and then use [`:lt()` jQuery selector](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) to show.

```
$("#parent>div").hide();

var n = 2;
$("#parent>div:lt(" + n + ")").show();

el.click(function () {
    n += 5;
    $("#parent>div:lt(" + n + ")").show();
});
```

Comment: may be the value will be 1 instead of 4

Comment: It can be any number >= 0.

Comment: But for the specific question asked, it should be 1.

Comment: According to the question it will be 1, I just mean it.

Comment: So for me to display f.ex. the next five divs with a click I could make the 1 into let's say var n and when I click on the button n = n+5 ?

Comment: It looks like in this case it is better to use `:lt()` instead. So you hide first, then then show more. I'll update the answer in a minute.

Comment: I tried this and it seems to be working, except the fact that it won't add 5... I removed the + and it did load the 6 first... Because for specific reasons I have to use onclick on the button so I think it breaks the variable. I tried using 
var r = $("#parent>div:visible").length();
var n = r + 5;
but it didn't work(?)

Comment: My bad, the parenthesis after .length shouldn't be there, I removed them and everything works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS:

```
#parent div:nth-child(n+3) {
    display: none;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xe5eogvr/)

Comment: Sigh. Hate the anonymous downvote. Maybe he/she missed: _or anything for that matter_

Comment: The downvote isn’t warranted, in my opinion. The OP did say “anything for that matter”, including CSS. This is a viable and simple solution. Upvoted.

Comment: Maybe, the only downside to that is, that it’s not easily reversible. But a CSS class can help: e.g. `#parent.topTwoShown div:nth-child(n+3)` as a selector, and then you only need to toggle the class `topTwoShown` on the parent element. Really simple.

Comment: @Xufox Yep. And I think I'd go that route in most cases, rather than using JavaScript for this. Especially since we are talking about elements already rendered to the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you could do it in jQuery:

```
// hide all the children
$("#parent>div").hide();
// unhide the two we care about
$("#child1").show();
$("#child2").show();
```

If you don't have known IDs for your elements, here's a more general solution:

```
$("#parent>div~div~div").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write jQuery code like so:

```
var visibleIndexes = [0, 1]
$("#parent").children().each(function(index) {
 if(visibleIndexes.indexOf(index) === -1){
   $(this).hide();
 } else {
   $(this).show();
 }
});
```

You can store indexes which you want to show in variable `visibleIndexes` or any other variable and pass it to this function

Answer (score 0):

A simple iterative approach:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    var somevalue = 3;
    $("#parent").children("div").each(
        function () {
            if(i > somevalue) $(this).hide();
            i++;
        });
});
```